# SQL and DB2 create command

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am going through a tutorial on how to use DB2 which is in a linux environment.

I am supposed to connect to a database, create a table, insert some data under db2 shell:

db2 connect to c3421m

db2

db2 => update command options using z ON Assignment_0.txt

db2 => update command options using v ON

db2 => CREATE TABLE BAND_2015   // gives error I got stuck here

// here is where I get stuck i am supposed to create a table and execute the follwing command under DB2 shell: CREATE TABLE BAND_2015

Code given:

```
create table band_2015 ( \

band_no integer not null primary key, \
band_name varchar(25) not null, \
band_home varchar(25) not null, \
band_type varchar(10) check (band_type in (‘concert’,’rock’,’jazz’,’military’)), \
b_start_date date not null, \
band_contact varchar(10) not null )
```

So how do I create this table? I was told to copy it to a text editor(do i save it as band_2015.sql ?). I am completely new to this but i have a lot of experience in other programming languages...

Comment: What happens if you just try a one-row command, like "create table t1 (c1 integer not null primary key)"?

Comment: db2 => create table t1 gives this error ->                                                 "DB21034E the command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a valid command line processor command. During SQL processing it returned: SQL0104N An unexpected token "table" was found following "create". Expected tokens may include: "TABLESPACE". SQLSTATE=42601"

Comment: You don't have to start the clp and do stuff from inside it. An alternative is to execute sql commands directly from the sh. I.e. `db2 "create table band_2015 ( \                                                    
band_no integer not null primary key, \
band_name varchar(25) not null, \
band_home varchar(25) not null, \
band_type varchar(10) check (band_type in ('concert','rock','jazz','military')), \                  
b_start_date date not null, \
band_contact varchar(10) not null )"`  You can also put your sql statement in a file and run them as `db2 -tf myfile.sql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the DB2 command-line processor by default commands and statements cannot span multiple lines, so it treats `CREATE TABLE BAND_2015` as a complete statement, which is of course not the case. In the code given to you those backslashes appear for a reason -- they indicate to the CLP that the statement continues on the next line.

Alternatively, you can start the CLP with the command line option `-t`, which will designate the semicolon, instead of the new line, as the statement terminator. You can then type the statement as you did, without the backslashes, and terminate it with the ";".

Comment: Ok so basically i just copy each line like db2 => create table band_2015 ( \  and so on in the terminal?

Comment: Actually nevermind, I found it out now thanks a lot for mentioning the backslash and terminate character

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the terminating character. By default in the carriage return (enter). However, for your tutorial, you should type multi-line commands. For this case, you change the terminator character by defining another

For semi-colon

```
db2 -t

select *
from table;
```

For at sign or any other character.

```
db2 -td@

select *
from table @
```

For no character:

```
db2

select * from table
```